# What's wrong with my jQuery plugin? (Won't animate)

Tags: jquery-plugins

I'm building my first jQuery plugins.  One is a tab-views switcher thing, and the other is a sliding pager thing. They can both be seen on this test page: http://test.benlwilliams.com/powerwash/

The problem I'm having is with the slider plugin called, blwslider(). The implementation can be found at the bottom of the test page.

I want to be able to have any number of sliders to be independent of one another.  The slider on the top works perfectly, but the slider on the bottom will not animate the sliding.

The bottom slider has 2 pages, and starts on the first page. You can see by clicking on the arrows that they appear and disappear correctly, as if the page had turned, but no animation is actually happening to turn the page. What makes me really confused is that if I use Firebug and put some "stops" in the turnPage function, all the variables have the correct values.  I can't find any reason why the page is not turning.

I also considered that maybe only the first appearance of a  .blwslider() is working for some reason. But I already swapped the order of the two chuncks of slider code, and still the slider with the #slider2 chunck refuses to work.

All the code is visible with firebug, but let me know if I need to post something specific.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out it has nothing to do with the plugin's implementation or structure, but rather a math problem when the slider has only two pages.